# Video frames interpolation in Java

Tags: java, video, interpolation

My use case:

1) read frames from a video file
2) generate more than one frame from each using an interpolation algorithm
3) create a new video by concatenating both original and generated frames (modifying FPS as needed to preserve original timing)

what's the easiest tool to learn for the purpose considering I've only programmed in Java in recent years?

Comment: Please make and show some effort.

Comment: My idea is pretty vague at the moment, but I already made some research on FFMPEG (not pure Java but could be used with some scripting), Martin Framework (good and extensible but seems to be oriented towards filtering: one-to-one frame transformation and no support for re-timing), pure Java (could do, but requires a lot of coding) so I was just looking for something supporting my use case I might have overlooked. BTW C coding is not completely out of question if there's a well documented tool/library